# Is there a way to write a macro to execute an Eclipse perspective's button repeatedly?

Tags: eclipse, macros, userscripts

Here's the deal:

I'm working with a language/tool called detica netreveal dataserver. It's very similar to the SAS language, but it's not sas.

The eclipse we use has a Dataserver perspective. When you create a file you can then run it by pressing the green run button that's part of the perspective, or pressing F8.

Now what I want to do is write some kind of script that tells eclipse to run certain files. Currently I have to click my through my project explorer, open the file, and press the button myself for each file. So I want to automate this process.

Can you think of a way to do this?

An alternative is, if I can find out what pressing the green button does (I think it runs some kind of jar on the the given file, but I'm not sure of the syntax of it etc), then I could write a command line script to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found, was that in Dataserver you can use the %INCLUDE command to run the other files.